# image to text pure customizable php script

Tags: php, html, image, image-processing, converters

I want convert from Image to Text. My requirement is different. I'm having 4 business cards in one image. I want to convert that to text in PHP.

[image]
I tried [HP API](https://www.idolondemand.com/developer/apis/ocrdocument#overview). But No Use for my requirement. 
Basic Idea is enough. Help me.

Comment: by using HP API, one cannot extract text from image check the link https://www.idolondemand.com/developer/docs/SupportedFormats.html

Comment: for text extraction you need OCR like Tesseract or whatever else it is out there

Comment: IDOL OnDemand is now Haven OnDemand. There are over 60 APIs in the catalog... https://dev.havenondemand.com/apis including OCR, which can be used for extracting text from images... https://dev.havenondemand.com/apis/ocrdocument#overview. Here is the link to the PHP client: https://github.com/HPE-Haven-OnDemand/havenondemand-php (I work for HPE Haven OnDemand)